# Post request in my thunderclient, trying to save data in my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 581)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.):

when i post the data is saved in the database

Comment: Your question doesn't give enough information to help. Can you please post some code snippets and better explain what you are trying to do?